# Are those sections $E_x$ still measurable a.e. when $E$ has measure $\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have a question about the  proposition below
(Proposition 5 on p. 419 of [Real analysis (by Halsey Royden and Patrick Fitzpatrick)](https://book4you.org/book/1012671/eae8ab)):

> **Proposition.** Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathscr{B},\nu)$ be two measure spaces (**not necessarily $\sigma$-finite**).
> Assume the measure $\nu$ is complete. Let $E \subset  X \times Y$ be measurable with respect to
> the product measure
> $\mu \times \nu$ and $(\mu \times \nu) (E) < \infty$. Then for almost all $x \in X$, the $x$-section of $E$, $E_x$,
> is a $\nu$-measurable
> subset of $Y$, the function $x \mapsto \nu (E_x)$ for $x \in X$ is a $\mu$-measurable function, and
> $$\left(\mu\times \nu\right)(E)=\int_X \nu \left(E_x\right) \, \text{d}\mu (x). $$

My question is:

> Does the proposition hold if $\left(\mu\times \nu\right)(E)=\infty$?

(Maybe the question seems unnecessary, since it does not arise in the proof of Fubini's theorem; but I think it is a very natural question.)

I know if the spaces are $\sigma$-finite, then it is clearly true. But for a non-$\sigma$-finite space, it seems non-trivial for me. I tried to find a counterexample; the most common space which is not $\sigma$-finite is an uncountable set endowed with its counting measure (however,  in this case, any subset is measurable, so it does not work). Could anybody give me some ideas? Would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT.** (The definition of the product measure $\mu\times \nu$). Let $\mathcal{S}:= \{A\times B: A\in \mathscr{A},B\in \mathscr{B}\}$ be a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets) (the sets in $\mathcal{S}$ are called "measurable rectangles"). We define a nonnegative set function $\mu\times \nu:\mathcal{S}\to [0,+\infty]$ by $(\mu\times \nu)(A\times B) = \mu(A)\cdot \nu (B)$, for $A\times B\in \mathcal{S}$. We can verify that the set function $\mu\times \nu$ defined on $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies  $(\mu\times\nu)(\varnothing)=0$ and countable additivity. [Carathéodory's Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem) says that we can define an [outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) $\left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*:2^{X\times Y}\to [0,+\infty]$ (which is called the Carathéodory outer measure induced by $\mu\times \nu$); and a subset $T\subset X\times Y$ is called $\left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*$-measurable  iff $\left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*(E)= \left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*(E\cap T)+\left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*(E\setminus T)$ for all $E\subset X\times Y$; moreover, the collection of all the $\left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*$-measurable sets forms a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}_{\left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*}$ on $X\times Y$ which contains $\mathcal{S}$ (and thus contains $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$), and the restriction of $\left(\mu\times\nu\right)^*$ to $\mathfrak{M}_{\left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*}$ becomes a measure (we still denote it by $\mu\times \nu$); and $\left(X\times Y, \mathfrak{M}_{\left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*},\mu\times \nu\right)$ is a complete measure space.

**In the proposition above, "$E\subset X\times Y$ be measurable with respect to the product measure $\mu\times \nu$" means $E$ is $\left(\mu\times \nu\right)^*$-measurable, i.e., $E\in\mathfrak{M}_{\left(\mu\times\nu\right)^*}$ (I do NOT mean that $E$ is in the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}\otimes \mathscr{B}:= \sigma\left(\mathcal{S}\right)$).**

Comment: Is the product measure defined on the product sigma algebra, or on the sigma algebra that comes out of the Caratheodory theorem (in particular, it is complete)? In short, what is your definition of the product measure? This is not quite clear in the non-sigma-finite case.

Comment: @PhoemueX I will add some details. Thx!